# Should a rotor be replaced if its surface is coarse or rough?

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor

When I was in the store to replace tires, the mechanic said I should replace two rotors.

The back rotors are smooth when I touch them but both front rotors are very coarse, like lines drawn on to them but only an inch of the radius surface is smooth. He says I should replace them and mere brake pads will not do it as it will wear out fast.

I asked about resurfacing and he says that will not do either.

I can see the difference and it kind of makes sense, but I know they tend to oversell as well. So should I replace the two rotors?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with resurfacing if done properly, yes resurface or replace both is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Rotors ( and drums) can be resurfaced as long as more than the specified minimum thickness remains. Minimum  thickness may be marked on rotors or you need to look it up. I would also look for a new garage.